Slurm services status=1/FAILURE for CentOs cluster
I have reinstalled slurm resource management on a HPC cluster. But it seems there is a problem on starting slurmd services. Here is the system status:
"systemctl status slurmd" shows:
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-11-10 11:31:24 +0130; 1 weeks 1 days ago

The slurm.conf output is:
#
# Example slurm.conf file. Please run configurator.html
# (in doc/html) to build a configuration file customized
# for your environment.
#
#
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
#
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ClusterName=linux
ControlMachine=master.cluster....
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/ctld
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurm/d
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
#ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid

ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
TaskPluginParam=cpusets
#PluginDir=
#FirstJobId=
#MaxJobCount=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PropagatePrioProcess=
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#Prolog=
#Epilog=
#SrunProlog=
#SrunEpilog=
#TaskProlog=
#TaskEpilog=
#TaskPlugin=
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=50
#TmpFS=
#UsePAM=
#

# GPU definition (Added by Surin 1399/11)
GresTypes=gpu

# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
#
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
#SchedulerAuth=
#SelectType=select/linear
SelectType=select/cons_res  # select partial node
#SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core_Memory
#FastSchedule=1
FastSchedule=0
PriorityType=priority/multifactor
PriorityDecayHalfLife=0
PriorityUsageResetPeriod=NONE
PriorityWeightFairshare=100000
#PriorityWeightAge=1000
PriorityWeightPartition=10000
#PriorityType=priority/multifactor
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=14-0
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=14-0
#PriorityWeightFairshare=100000
#PriorityWeightAge=1000
#PriorityWeightPartition=10000
#PriorityWeightJobSize=1000
#PriorityMaxAge=1-0
DefMemPerCPU=2000
# LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompLoc=
#
# ACCOUNTING
#JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
#
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageHost=master
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStorageUser=
#
# COMPUTE NODES
# OpenHPC default configuration
# Edited by Surin 1399/11
#AccountingStorageEnforce=limits
AccountingStorageEnforce=QOS,Limits,Associations
#TaskPlugin=task/affinity
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=MEMLOCK
#AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
Epilog=/etc/slurm/slurm.epilog.clean
NodeName=cn0[1-5] NodeHostName=cn0[1-5]  RealMemory=128307 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 Feature=HyperThread State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=gp01 NodeHostName=gp01 RealMemory=128307 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 Feature=HyperThread Gres=gpu:4 State=UNKNOWN
#PartitionName=all  Nodes=cn0[1-5],gp01 MaxTime=INFINITE  State=UP Oversubscribe=EXCLUSIVE
PartitionName=all  Nodes=cn0[1-5],gp01 MaxTime=10-00:00:00  State=UP MaxNodes=1
PartitionName=normal Nodes=cn0[1-5] Default=YES MaxTime=10-00:00:00  State=UP MaxNodes=1
#PartitionName=normal Nodes=cn0[1-5] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE  State=UP Oversubscribe=EXCLUSIVE
PartitionName=gpu Nodes=gp01 MaxTime=10-00:00:00  State=UP
SlurmctldParameters=enable_configless
ReturnToService=1
HealthCheckProgram=/usr/sbin/nhc
HealthCheckInterval=300

scontrol show node cn01 shows:
NodeName=cn01 CoresPerSocket=16 
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=64 CPULoad=N/A
   AvailableFeatures=HyperThread
   ActiveFeatures=HyperThread
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=cn01 NodeHostName=cn01 
   RealMemory=128557 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=N/A Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=DOWN* ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=64278 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=all,normal 
   BootTime=None SlurmdStartTime=None
   CfgTRES=cpu=64,mem=128557M,billing=64
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
   Reason=undraining

"scontrol ping" also works as:
 Slurmctld(primary) at master.cluster... is UP

"systemctl start slurmd" shows:
Job for slurmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slurmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

"systemctl status slurmd.service" shows:
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-11-18 17:02:50 +0130; 41s ago
  Process: 219025 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... slurmd[219025]: fatal: Unable to determine this slurmd's NodeName
Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... systemd[1]: slurmd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... systemd[1]: Unit slurmd.service entered failed state.
Nov 18 17:02:50 master.cluster.... systemd[1]: slurmd.service failed.

"journalctl -xe" output is:
Nov 18 17:04:54 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:05:04 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:05:08 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:05:12 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:05:22 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:05:26 master.cluster.... dhcpd[2250]: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:35:09:f8:13:40 via eno2: network eno2: no free leases
Nov 18 17:06:34 master.cluster.... munged[2514]: Purged 2 credentials from replay hash

slurmd.services contains the following information:
[Unit]
Description=Slurm node daemon
After=munge.service network.target remote-fs.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/slurm/slurm.conf

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/slurmd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
KillMode=process
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
Delegate=yes


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[root@master system]# which slurmd
/usr/sbin/slurmd
[root@master system]# cat slurmd.service 
[Unit]
Description=Slurm node daemon
After=munge.service network.target remote-fs.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/slurm/slurm.conf

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/slurmd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
KillMode=process
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
Delegate=yes


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

For "which slurmd" command I get this address: /usr/sbin/slurm
ls -l /usr/sbin/slurmd shows:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 69 Nov 10 10:54 /usr/sbin/slurmd -> /install/centos7.9/compute_gpu/rootimg/usr/sbin/slurmd

